# Problem with Firestore and billing that goes up exponentially

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In a collection, approximately 1000 records are written per day per operating user (approximately 10 operating users in the field), I have a query that obtains the records made during the day in order to keep track of the points covered by mobile users in the field:

```
const lastActividadGPS = await firestore
          .collection("Actividad_GPS")
          .where("instancia", "==", instancia) //instancia
          .where("user_id", "==", parseInt(ejecutivo.user_id))
          .where("fecha_hora", ">=", dayStart.toDate())
          .where("fecha_hora", "<=", dayEnd.toDate())
          .orderBy("fecha_hora", "desc")
          .get();
```

The collection:

[image]

It happens that when I have 100K+ of documents accumulated in the collection and 1-3 users make queries (they execute this query internally from the web platform) up to 30M readings are made per day, but if I delete all the data it normalizes and I have up to 50K of readings per day. I have not been able to identify the problem with the excessive readings - when the collection has a lot of data - and I do not know if firebase at the time of sorting reads all the documents and then filters it.

We also tried including limit in the query but it didn't work.

Comment: We can't observe your database, queries, and variables going into the queries, so there's not much we can do here.  You're going to have to dig in deeper to figure out how many documents are actually coming back for a given query.  Firestore doesn't simply omit filters or ordering - it always does exactly as you instruct it.

Comment: "I do not know if firebase at the time of sorting reads all the documents and then filters it" Nope, it doesn't. Explanation below. One way to troubleshoot is to have your application log the number of documents it reads for each query, and check if those match your expectation. If you can't determine this from local debugging, consider logging to a central location and shipping that with the app to your users.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider changing from Firestore to Realtime Database. In my searches, I found that Firestore charges by query which makes it very inefficient if you plan to use it. However, Realtime Database charges by database size which makes more sense as that happens when you have more users and are thus making more money.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know if firebase at the time of sorting reads all the documents and then filters it

Firestore queries execute on indexes that you define, only allows queries that it can actually execute on those indexes, and only read (and charge document reads and bandwidth) for documents that are matched by those conditions in your query.

So if you are charged for more reads than you expect, it's because those documents are actually matched in the queries you execute.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that time series data deserves special handling. It boils down to hardware utilization, how data is stored and accessed at the physical layer. [Mongo talks about it](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/). BTW I'm not saying that Firebase/Firestore isn't appropriate for your needs, just sharing that time series records get special attention / modeling.

> #### Benefits
>
> Compared to normal collections, storing **time series data** in time series collections improves query efficiency and reduces the
> disk usage for time series data and secondary indexes.
>
> Time series collections use an underlying columnar storage format and
> store data in time-order with an automatically created clustered
> index. The columnar storage format provides the following benefits:
>
> - Reduced complexity for working with time series data
> - Improved query efficiency
> - Reduced disk usage
> - Reduced I/O for read operations
> - Increased WiredTiger cache usage